# integral with difficult U substitution

Tags: integration

$$\frac{r_0}{R}\int_{r_0}^r \frac{1}{r} {\sqrt {\frac{R^2- r^2}{r^2-r_0^2}}dr}=\int_{0}^ θ dθ$$

I want to show that if we set

$$ u= {\sqrt {\frac{r^2-r_0^2}{R^2- r^2}}}$$

then the integral becomes

$$θ=\frac{r_0}{R}\int_{0}^u \left(\frac{1}{\left(r_0\over R \right)^2+ u^2}-\frac{1}{1+u^2}\right) du $$

Can anyone help with the intermediate steps.

Comment: I think you may want to use another alphabet for $r$ as the boundary to make it clearer, because $r$ is already used as the variable for integration. Is the $r$ a constant or another variable?

Answer (score 0):

You almost made it $$u= {\sqrt {\frac{r^2-r_0^2}{R^2- r^2}}}\implies r=\frac{\sqrt{R^2+r_0^2 u^2}}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}\implies dr=\frac{u (r_0-R) (r_0+R)}{\left(u^2+1\right)^{3/2} \sqrt{a^2 u^2+R^2}}du$$ This makes $$I=\frac{r_0}{R}\int{\frac 1 r\sqrt {\frac{R^2- r^2}{r^2-r_0^2}}dr}=\int\frac{r_0 u^2 (r_0-R) (r_0+R)}{R \left(u^2+1\right) \left(r_0^2 u^2+R^2\right)}du$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition to get $$I=\int \Big(\frac{r_0}{R \left(u^2+1\right)}-\frac{r_0 R}{r_0^2 u^2+R^2}\Big)du$$

Comment: One question in the first line.Where did α come from?

Comment: @kostas. From typo's !! I was too lazy to write $r_0$ which I replaced by $a$ and I forgot to change it back in a few places. Sorry about it ! Cheers.

Comment: Also in the integral there is a fraction of 1/r in front of the sqrt.

Comment: one more typo and I repeat my apologies.

Comment: Another one is that for solving for r on the numerator we get $$ u^2R^2+r_0^2 $$